# Error in order of values of SQL Server Management Studio while taking query result as csv file

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssms

Order of values changing while taking SQL query result as csv file.

The result of SQL query:

[image: result]

But when saving to a `.csv` file, it looks like this:

[image: csv]

[image: csv]

I need the `.csv` file like shown in SQL result

Comment: You presumably have some line-break characters at the end of some of your "ItemName" values, so that when exporting to CSV it causes Excel to interpret new lines.  Some characters, like line-breaks (and others) will really appear "hidden" in the grid output when you're running a query in SQL Management Studio.  You'll either potentially need to do a bit of a tidy-up of the data in SQL (if those "ItemName" values are not really meant to have line-breaks), or you'll need to use a different character (that isn't in your data) as the "record delimiter" when exporting the CSV

Comment: Additionally, you should really include your sample queries/data as text within your question, rather than images.  That is the standard for StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

in your data has ','  that  ',' has default delimiter

you can

1.concatenate start and end " in this column for

example

```
case when [AddressLine1] is not null and [AddressLine1]!='' then
      '"'+ISNULL([AddressLine1],'')+'"' else [AddressLine1] end  as AddressLine1
```

2.replace ',' with other character

example

```
case when [AddressLine1] is not null and [AddressLine1]!='' then
      replace([AddressLine1],',','-') else [AddressLine1] end  as AddressLine1
```

1.use sqlcmd (change  separator )

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16
sqlcmd -S . -Q "select * from Employees;" -o "C:\employees.csv" -W -w 1024 -s "," -h-1

sqlcmd is the command name. -S . specifies the server name.

-Q "select * from Employees;" is the query that fetches data to be exported.

-o "C:\employees.csv" defines the file that stores the exported data.

-W removes the trailing white spaces you see in the command line tool output after each value. -w 1024 defines the length of the line in the CSV file.

-s "," defines the separator for the column values; here, a comma.

4.use ssis